# SSIS returns 0 rows

Tags: sql, ssis, agent

I am having an issue I can not figure out.  I created an SSIS package that uses a SQL command to retrieve data from Server2.  The query is very simple, however, it references a view in a join.  If I execute the SSIS package manually on Server1, it retrieves 925 rows and inserts it into the appropriate table in Server1. The problem starts when I schedule this SSIS package to run nightly.  It succeeds on the first step (truncating the table on Server1 in preparation for retrieving the rows from Server2), but, when I look at the table, there are 0 rows.  When I modify the Query to remove the join that references a view (getting undesired results), the scheduled SSIS works perfectly, although the recordset I get back is not what I wanted, because I need that JOIN.  I don't see how it can be a permissions issue as it works fine without the VIEW.  Is there something I'm missing?  Thanks for the help.

The following query works only if I execute the SSIS manually:  FilteredAccount is a VIEW
It should return over 900 rows and does if I run manually, but returns 0 if executing the SSIS via Agent.

```
SELECT B.epc_cosmid, A.consultant, A.region
FROM Consultant2TC AS A JOIN FilteredAccount AS B ON A.consultant = B.epc_serviceconsultantidname
```

If I change the query to the one below  in the SSIS package and schedule it, it works fine:

```
SELECT A.consultant, A.region
FROM Consultant2TC AS A
```

Comment: I'm no expert on the agent, but I'd check that the context the agent job runs in has necessary permissions to access the view

Comment: Any chance that there are two FilteredAccount objects? One in the default schema for the account the SQL Agent uses and one that is in your default schema?

Comment: Try changing to this just to get some certainty around the configuration: `SELECT A.consultant, A.region, @@servername as SN, db_name() as db, suser_sname() as uname
FROM Consultant2TC`. Load that into your table overnight just to be absolutely certain about where the data is coming from. You could also add a load directly from the view at the same time just to see what state that view is at that time of night.

Comment: @ElectricLlama I tried your suggestion and the job captured the correct server name, username, and db name and inserted it into a table.  I just do not know what is going on.  I have modified the job dozens of times and it executes fine, however, each time I reference the view, it inserts 0 rows into the table.  The account used to execute the job is a sysadmin account, so, shouldn't it have permissions to execute any views or functions (the view also includes user functions)?  I have enabled logging and it shows no errors, just states "0 rows were transferred".

Comment: I just wanted to clarify, that it only returns 0 rows if I schedule the query as a job.  If I run it manually via SSMS, it works perfectly.  Yet, if I copy that query from SSMS and paste it into a a job as a step, then execute that job: 0 rows transferred, no errors in the log, nothing.

Comment: So time is not  factor, it's only when you run it as a job? Can you verify that the user returned is the same user you connect through SSMS as? I suggest you do a dataload directly from the view into a table into SSMS just to inspect it's contents when run as a job. I'm suspicious of a view called _FilteredAccount_. Can you post the definition? It may be filtering records based on the connected user and if that user is different you'll get different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're getting different results from an agent job and your own login, an obvious place to start looking is permissions. What results do you get when you run the query from SSMS **while logged in using the agent's credentials**?